# Core Data modeling of relationships

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

I'm modeling my app in Core Data.  I have an object called 'stats' that will have a 'player', a 'team', and a 'game' associated with each object. Once these stats objects are stored, I imagine querying for them by any one or more of these attributes (player, team, game).  See model below.

[image: Core Data Model]

Question 1: Does it make sense to model these as 'relationships' as opposed to 'attributes'.

Question 2: When retrieving I would like to form my NSPredicates using objects and not have to keep track of unique IDs names for each player, team, or game.  If I store the player, team, and game objects (as opposed to unique IDs or names) with each entity, what is the best way to retrieve them.  Would the following work if I wanted to retrieve all stats objects for a particular 'team' (someTeamObject) or do I need to query by ObjectID?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"team == %@", someTeamObject];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If I understand your question right, yes, it makes sense to model these as separate objects with relationships between them. It will especially help when fetching various objects; you could, for example, get the single Player associated with a given Stat, or get all the Stats for a Game. This leads into your second question:
2. Instead of using a predicate, note that your relationships have names; instead of building a full NSFetchRequest with associated NSPredicate, you could just call the relevant accessor method. For your request to get all the Stat objects for a Team, you just call `[team stats]` and you get back an NSArray of Stat objects.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  WRT answer 2, yes I can now access all the stats for a team as per your example, and since I have inverse relationships to the 'player' and the 'game' from the stats object I guess I can further refine that array by cycling through each object and testing for these objects.  My concern is that the [team stats] NSSet may be very large and that would be loaded into memory in order to do the other tests.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?  For example having the database do the work as opposed to the client?  Truth is there are more attributes to filter on(was keeping simple)

Comment: JMH: I'd recommend reading up on faults, especially in the Core Data Programming Guide and the NSManagedObject class reference. Notably, you can call `isEqual:` on managed objects without firing a fault, which makes it possible for you to iterate through that set without a large memory requirement. If you need to access properties of each managed object, though, you're right - it's probably more efficient for you to construct a fetch request with NSPredicate to do the work. In that case, I believe your original example would work using `==` comparison.

Comment: Tim, the faults info in the Core Data Programming Guide was right on the money.  Thanks.  I think I will use NSPredicates to do the work in most cases.  I guess it wouldn't hurt to keep the relationships as defined in my original question.